# psexec start program doesn't work

Tags: windows, batch

Id like to kill and start a program on a remote machine with psexec.
I use the following batch-file (c:/users/user is psexec root)

```
cd c:/users/user
psexec \\computername cmd /c "taskkill /im SwyxIt!.exe /f"
psexec \\computername cmd /c "taskkill /im CLMgr.exe /f"
timeout -t 5
psexec \\computername cmd /c "start C:\Program Files (x86)\SwyxIt!\SwyxIt!.exe"
```

but the program doesn't start!

also if i run the start command like this 
`psexec \\computername cmd /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\SwyxIt!\SwyxIt!.exe"`

It doesn't start.

If i run the command without psexec on my own machine `start "C:\Program Files (x86)\SwyxIt!\SwyxIt!.exe"` it works just fine.

any suggestions? I have administrator priviliges on all remote machines.

Comment: Does the program require user interaction? Have you tried it on remote machines with the -i switch?

Comment: thx for the hint with -i, unfortunately it doesn't work. it exits with error code 3. i read that it means "path not found" but i'm very sure the path exists on the remote machine. i tried to put the path in quotes "" but it also didn't work.

Comment: Dollars to donuts you've got the quoting mixed up somehow - this `"start C:\Program Files (x86)\SwyxIt!\SwyxIt!.exe"` is going to try starting `c:\Program`. Note when you try it on your machine you quote the path, not including "start". Also note that the first quoted parameter to `start` is the title of the command window so I'm surprised if that works fine on your machine...

Comment: Aside from what @TessellatingHeckler said it would look like:    psexec \\computername cmd /c "Start "C:\Program Files (x86)\SwyxIt!\SwyxIt!.exe""  (Yes you CAN use double quotes in PSexec. Other than that, are you running these commands against a 32bit machine? That would also explain why the path would not be found

Comment: @Get-HomeByFiveOClock from his comment - `"i tried to put the path in quotes "" but it also didn't work"`. Presumably because that command will start an empty command prompt titled "c:\program files (x86)\swyxit..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i got it now. I also needed to activate the `-s` parameter

With this command it works

```
psexec -s -i \\computername cmd /c "start /i "SwyxIt!" "C:\Program Files (x86)\SwyxIt!\SwyxIt!.exe""
```

thank you for your help

Comment: ` -s         Run the remote process in the System account.`